# Should I change app content rating in the play console or change the ad maturity level in the admob dashboard?

Tags: android, admob, google-play-console, policy

Recently one of my app update has been rejected because of **Inappropriate Ads policy**. They provided me an image of the ad as well. I found that the add was card related game which partially directs to gambling.

After studying I found that my app's content rating is 3+ which generated automatically after answering some questions of IARC. As we do not show any violence or sexual or gambling content so the content rating was 3+.

But Admob showing some game and video player installation ad which contains some violence and nudity. Maybe that's why Admob rejected our update.

Now should I need to change my content rating? If we change the content rating will it make a huge differences in play store ranking which leads to loss in earning?
Or should I just change the Admob ad content rating settings? Which one will be good for me?

However changing Admob content rating is already giving me warning of loosing impression and earning. What is the best approach to handle this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about app store policies are off topic here.  As are questions about business and finance, which is what this boils down to (a product decision on size of market vs revenue potential per user).

Comment: Is there a place where the OPs question would be more appropriate? Obviously this isn't the place. I think a recommendation would be wonderful for the OP though. @GabeSechan